# python tkinter image "..." doesn't exist error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = Tk()
window.geometry("350x670")

topBar = Frame(window, bg= "black", width=350, height=70).pack()
middleBar = Frame(window, bg= "grey", width=350, height=530).pack()
botBar = Frame(window, bg= "black", width=350, height=70).pack()

imgLabel1 = Label(topBar, image="profile-pic.jpg").place(x=50,y=50)


window.mainloop()
```

This is my code. I want to set an image in topBar frame. When I run the code, I get this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "profile-pic.jpg" doesn't exist>

How can I solve this error? Thank you

Comment: You need to create an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` and pass this to `image` option to `Label` widget: `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="profile-pic.jpg")`, and then `imgLabel1 = Label(topBar, image=image)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` to the `image` option of `Label` widget:

```py
...
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="profile-pic.jpg")
imgLabel1 = Label(topBar, image=image)
imgLabel1.place(x=50, y=50)
...
```